# How to call Enums in *ngIf condition Angular 8

Tags: typescript, enums, angular8

I declare an enum type in my TS file, and I need to use as a condition on my HTML,
but the "value"'s of enum was undefined despite of declare and inheritance from the export of that enum.

```
export enum PlanType {
    Marketing = 1,
    Installation = 2,
    MarketingAndInstallation = 3,
    Collect = 4,
    SwitchingDevice = 5,
    Periodic = 6,
    Case = 7
}

.TS file
planType: PlanType;
```

```html
<div *ngIf="model.planType === planType.Case">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your component class, you can add the following method:

```
isPlanTypeCase(): boolean {
    return this.planType == PlanType.Case;
}
```

This method can then be used in your template in the following way:

```
<div *ngIf="isPlanTypeCase()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer:

```
*ngIf="model.planType.Periodic"
```